# Why does the each method require the value it looped to be assigned to a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working on Rails and found lack of knowledge in my understanding of the `each` method.

Not sure why the `each` method requires the variable `|message|`

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
    <h2><%= message.title %></h2>
    <%= link_to "View Message", message_path(message), class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It is called *iteration*. It is just like writing any *loops* in ruby.

Comment: How would you refer to the current element without a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you loop through `@messages`, you need some way to refer to each element to make it available to your code. Ruby does this by passing each element to the block one at a time as a variable. The pipe syntax is used in Ruby for naming block variables in *any* block context, not just `each`.

Ruby isn't going to decide on its own that when you're iterating on `@messages` that each element should be referred to as a `message`. You need to make that decision explicitly and assign the variable name in the pipes. You don't need to call the variable `message`. You could call it `hot_dog`. But you need to assign the element to *something* or else you won't be able to access it and what's the point of the loop?

```
<% @messages.each do |hot_dog| %>
    <h2><%= hot_dog.title %></h2>
    <%= link_to "View Message", message_path(hot_dog), class: "btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: There are a few (somewhat complex) cases were if you know you have 1 parameter you can get away with not defining it.  #1 is if the parameter is a block, you can call the block with `yield` instead of defining a variable for it. #2 the cases where you can use `&:something`, but those don't actually code as a block, even if they compile to one.  Over all though your post answers the question completely +1.

Answer (score 7):

> Not sure why the each method requires the variable `|message|`

It doesn't *require* it. You can very well omit it.

```
<% @messages.each do %>
```

But, in this case, what you going to output in your `<h2>`?

Answer (score 1):

`each` doesn't change the value of `self` in the block vs outside it. For example:

```
class Foo
  def bar1; "hello"; end
  def bar2; [1].each { puts bar1 }
end
Foo.new.bar2 # => "hello"
```

In this example, the `bar1` method call is the same as saying `puts self.bar1`, and so you need to maintain the same value of `self` as outside the block.

If you wanted to set the value of `self` in the block to the current iteratee, you could use a method like this:

```
def bound_each(&blk)
  each { |x| x.instance_eval &blk }
end
[1].bound_each { puts self } # => 1
```

However there isn't anything like this built into Ruby or Rails core as far as I'm aware.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45556401/2981429 for a similar method which bounds the `self` to the Enumerable (`[1]`, here)