# Way to refer to the receiver of 'Array#each'

Tags: ruby

I am iterating over an array, and I'm wondering if there's a shorthand to refer to the receiver of `#each` (or `#each_with_index`) method from within the iteration.

`self` returns `main`.

Comment: There are four answers so far. It seems to me that none of them address your question. My understanding is that you have `collection.each { |c| .... }` and want to know if the value of `collection` can be determined from with the block without changing anything outside the block. If that is correct the answer is 'no'.

Comment: Why do you want to / have to do that? How does your code look like? What are you trying to achieve? If you want to access other (neighboring?) elements, there are other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just reference it:

```
my_thing.each {|one_thing| puts my_thing }
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I have it, but I was wondering if there was some ruby shorthand for it. Specifically because it's actually a Rails app and this array is an ActiveRecord Collection, so I didn't want to have to access the db again

Comment: @pholls, just load your collection once by setting variable before iteration

Comment: I think it would help to see the real use case here.

Comment: @ilya, that's what I've done; I just wanted to know if there was a Ruby equivalent of `this` in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure that referencing the AR Collection would be problematic.

Comment: @pholls: You're oversimplifying.. We've got blocks here. Equivalent of `this` exists, it's IIRC `self`, but in this context it is not what you think. `each` is called on my_thing, and inside `each` any this/self would point to `my_thing` . However, inside the **block**, the this/self points to the object that owns the method within which this block is defined in.. I mean `class Foo; def Bar; [1,2,3].each{|n|   puts self.class }; end; end`  will print out `Foo` since you called `foo.Bar`. Code contained in blocks are considered to be part of `Bar` from `Foo`, not `each` from collection.

Comment: @pholis In response to `I didn't want to have to access the db again`, be aware that ActiveRecord caches database query responses made in the same request by default, so rerunning the exact same query, while expensively instantiating new Ruby objects, won't make a second DB query. Keep an eye out for `CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT...` in your logs.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty similar to the answer I gave here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45421168/2981429 but slightly different.

First off, you can create a scope with `self` bound to the array, and then execute the `each` in that scope:

```
[1].instance_exec do
  # in this scope, self is the array
  # thus we can use just 'each' because the self is inferred
  each do |x|
    # note that since 'class' is a special keyword,
    # it needs to be explicitly namespaced on self
    puts self.class, x
  end
end
# => prints Array, 1
```

You can create a utility function to do this, if you want:

```
def bound_each(enumerable, &blk)
  enumerable.instance_exec { each &blk }
end
bound_each([1]) { |x| puts self.class, x }
# prints Array, 1
```

Comment: You can only refer to the receiver from within the iteration because you assigned it to `self` (via `instance_exec`) from outside the iteration. If you have that level of control, you could just as well assign the array to a variable.

Comment: @Stefan yes, but you get the benefit of not having to namespace method calls. It might not be the best approach from a separation of concerns perspective, but it's still useful for DSLs, or if you want to quickly open a one-off scope without creating a class or something, or for the purpose of binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your `each` method within an [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) block and reference the original receiver like that.

```
[1, 2, 3].tap { |i| i.each { |j| p i.dup << j } }
# [1, 2, 3, 1]
# [1, 2, 3, 2]
# [1, 2, 3, 3]
#=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Here the receiving object is `[1, 2, 3]` and is passed to the block-variable `i` which we can use locally or in nested scopes such as `each`'s block.

Avoid modifying the receiving object else you may end up with undesired results such as an infinite array. Using `dup` could allay this possibility.

Comment: how could you end up with an infinite array?

Comment: @maxpleaner If you ran the above code without `dup` then we have: `[1, 2, 3].tap { |i| i.each { |j| p i << j } }
`. During each iteration you're pushing a new element into the receiver `i` so there will always be something to iterate over and repeat the pushing of new elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. As far as I know it's not possible – the closest I can come up with would be to use `inject` (or `reduce`) and explicitly pass the receiver as an argument. A bit pointless, but there might be a use-case for it that I'm not seeing:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.inject(a) do |this, element|
  this == a #=> true
  this.include?(element) #=> true
  this
end
```

Apart from looking a bit redundant, you have to be very sure to return `this` at the end of each iteration, as the return value will become `this` in the next iteration. For that reason (and the fact that you could just reference your collection in an `each` block, as in David's answer) I don't recommend using this.

---

Edit - as Simple Lime pointed out in the comments – I missed the obvious [`Enumerator#with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object), which has the same (rather pointless) effect, but without the drawback of having to return `this` at the end of each iteration.  For example:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.map.with_object(a) do |element, this|
  this == a #=> true, for each iteration
end
```

I still don't recommend that you use this though.

Comment: you could also just use `a.each.with_object(a) { |element, this| ... }` instead of misusing `inject`, but yeah point still stands, that since `a` is already still available, it's redundant